# How does solr weigh synonym values when searched?

Tags: search, solr, synonym

I'm trying to wrap my head around Solr and how to improve my search results. I'm using synonyms.txt file to add like words and have them equal each other,

Example:

```
bar = dive bar
bar = club
bar = wine bar
bar = beer on tap
dive bar = club
dive bar = wine bar
dive bar = beer on tap
club = wine bar
club = beer on tap
wine bar = beer on tap
```

If someone searches using the word 'bar' will it weigh results so that content with the word bar are displayed before other synonyms as well as, if someone searches 'wine bar' will the wine bar listings be weighted higher in the results compared to club?

Answer (score 1):

**Solr treats equally the searched term as well as its synonyms**. Lets take an example. Below is the synonym.txt

```
bar,dive bar,club,wine bar
```

If someone searches for the '**dive bar**' then it does not means that search results with 'dive bar' will comes on top. It could be results containing '**bar**' word.

There is another parser available that you can use to handle this situation better. Below is the link.
https://nolanlawson.com/2012/10/31/better-synonym-handling-in-solr/

By using this parser you can give **more boost to the searched term in comparison to their synonyms**.